# how does facebook login and register api works

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a site with custom login and register option which asks username, password, email, dob, gender.

Now, what i want is to add Facebook login page for my website. and if user allow to share his information with my site then it will retrieve these general information from it and then show the status of login. And also, if user already login to Facebook then it will show his status instead of Facebook Login Button.

I doesn't know how this API works and how to code it. I'm using php and MySQL for my website.

Answer (score 0):

Read below article. I followed this in my website.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

I can provide code sample but that is on Zend Framework.

Comment: While your article may in fact answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Stack Overflow is only as useful as its questions and answers, and if your blog host goes down or your URLs get moved around, this answer becomes useless. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for registration and login with/without Facebook is done with the registration plugin.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/

However your question seems too wide to answer it precisely, you must read a lot in order to log in your users from Facebook and match them with an account on your site.

At least you should get one of the server side Facebook libraries. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/

Hope that helps.